# Warning Avoid nesting promises promise/no-nesting

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I am trying to implement to send push notification from one device to another device function with my mobile app. By referring video tutorials. But when I try to deploy it I am getting some errors

Here is the code

```
 'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("/users/{user_id}/notification/{notification_id}").onWrite((change, context)=> {

    const user_id = context.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
    return admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user_id).collection(notification).doc(notification_id) .get().then( (queryResult)=> {

        const from_user_id = queryResult.data().from;
        const from_data = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(from_user_id).get();
        const to_data = admin.firestore().collection("users").doc(user_id).get();
        return Promise.all([from_data, to_data]).then(result => {
            const from_name = result[0].data().name;
            const to_name = result[1].data().name;
           console.log("from :"+ from_name+" To "+ to_name);
        });


    });
});
```

[ERROR]

```
  16:10  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
  16:49  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return

✖ 2 problems (1 error, 1 warning)

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `eslint .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/akhilbatchu/.npm/_logs/2018-09-23T08_07_51_854Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

I'm to new in Javascript , so I'm really lost with this type of messages.

How can I solve this?

Please help me how to solve this issue

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This article has an explanation on the antipattern: https://www.datchley.name/promise-patterns-anti-patterns/

Comment: and as for second one check https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/master/docs/rules/always-return.md

Comment: Do you want to do anything with `from_name` or `to_name` other than logging it?